# ssis - No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am working with SSIS 2008. i am getting error on sql task editor
query as Error: Executing the query "SELECT  SUBSTRING(?, 8, 2) + SUBSTRING(?, 10, 2) +..." failed with the following error: "No value given for one or more required parameters.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Execute sql task containing query

SELECT  SUBSTRING(?, 8, 2) + SUBSTRING(?, 10, 2) + '20' + SUBSTRING(?, 10, 2) AS File_Date

i had selected result_Set as Single_row

The parameter mapping used containing field name as
var_name:User::File_Name_update 
direction:input
Data type: varchar
parameter_name:0
Parameter_size:-1

The result set i have added is:
Result_Name:File_date
variable_name:User::File_date

So here i am getting the file date from the updated input file name in substring.May i know what am i doing wrong to handle the above scenario?

Comment: from what you have listed you have three parameters but you are only mapping one of them.

Comment: No,here i have used '+' as concatenation as single row...correct me i am wrong

Comment: Doesn't matter if those are over one line or 3 lines. In the eyes of the compiler you have declared 3 separate and unconnected variables. Because oledb connections use an index based parameter mapping you must explicitly  map every instance of a variable even if they are the same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to map 3 parameters for that query. If you want to map only one, you can do this:

```
declare @str varchar(max) = ?
SELECT SUBSTRING(@str, 8, 2) + SUBSTRING(@str, 10, 2) + '20' + SUBSTRING(@str, 10, 2) AS File_Date
```

Comment: depending on the version of sql server you may need to separate the declare and set statements. I am pretty sure that you could do a combined statement starting in 2008 but 2005 would require the statement be split.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, My local machine supports date format as 'mm-dd', But when I deploy in server It is accepting only 'dd-mm'. So, I solved the same issue after changing the format. This could help someone.